# GitHub Action pb with environment variable

Tags: github, platformio

I set up environment variable in my GitHub workflow to force PlatformIO use repo clone just before but does work.
can somebody see something wrong in my code.

**this is my code:**

```
name: Build

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
strategy:
  matrix:
    os: [macos-latest, windows-latest, ubuntu-latest]

steps:
- name: Set up Python
  uses: actions/setup-python@v1
  with:
    python-version: '3.x'
- name: Install dependencies
  run: 
      |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install platformio
- name: Check out Luos repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Create env repo
  run: 
       |
    cd ..
    git clone https://github.com/Luos-io/LuosHAL.git
    git clone https://github.com/Luos-io/Examples.git
    export PLATFORMIO_LIB_EXTRA_DIRS=/home/runner/work/Luos
- name: Run PlatformIO
  run:
       |
    platformio run -d Examples/Projects/Button/
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I find the pb:

export PLATFORMIO_LIB_EXTRA_DIRS=/home/runner/work/Luos need to be in the same run as platformio run -d Examples/Projects/Button/